# Issue writing data-sets to an .hdf5 file within a for loop

Tags: python, file, h5py

I am iterating over a number of files and reading out the information I want, this is being stored in a numpy array that I then write out to an h5py file object with a unique name (e.g. outputdataset_1, outputdataset_2 . . . ), however when the script runs it only writes out the final dataset to file (outputdataset_numFiles).

For the sake of simplicity, all the file parsing has been abstracted into an if loop and the function "get_data", it is fair and valid to assume that when the code gets to the end of the file, the pts data structure contains all the correct values.

```py
for num in range(1,numFiles):
    with h5py.File("outputFileName.hdf5", "w") as f:
        with open("fileAddress" +str(num)) as file:
                lineNum = 0
                while True:
                    line = file.readline(lineNum)
                    if not line and lineNum != 0:
                        s = 'outputdataset_' +str(num)
                        dset = f.create_dataset(s,pts.shape,data=pts)
                        break;
                    if line == criteria:
                        pts = get_data(pts,line)
                    lineNum += 1
```

Comment: You open (and overwrite) the output file for each input file.  You read a non-blank line and put the values in `pts`.  But you don't do anything with that.  Shouldn't you be collecting values from multiple lines?  Only the last `pts` value is being written.  I think you need to practice with a simpler case where you can follow the iterations in detail.

Comment: my mistake I simplified the code a little too much, I can assure you that the data collection from file is working perfectly. I'll edit the example now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the order of the lines `for num in range(…)` and `with h5py.File(…)`; the way you wrote it, you'll close the file each time you load in a new file, and since `h5py.File()` is called with mode `'w'`, it will (correctly) overwrite `"outputfilename.hdf5"` in each loop.

Solution: just switch these lines around.

Alternatively (but this likely requires more code!) you could use the "append" file mode, i.e. `with h5py.File("outputFileName.hdf5", "a") as f` — but then you will likely run into `RuntimeError: 'Unable to create link (name already exists)'` if you run the script more than once (iteratively). You *can* of course write additional code that checks for pre-existing paths in the `hdf5` file and implements some kind of update/replace logic, but that may take a bit of time to code.